# Exception when no_data_found, i want to assign two variables to null

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql

I have written a select query to fetch two column values, in case of exception I want to assign those variables to null in ORACLE STORED PROCEDURE.

**eg**:

```
select column A, column B into l_a, l_b 
  from ......
exception 
  when no_data_found then 
    l_a: = null and l_b := null ;
```

Comment: And what precisely is stopping you from progressing towards this noble goal?

Comment: If I am writing like this, it is giving error! pls-00103: encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:

Comment: that is typo here, i have written correctly in oracle

Comment: Hmmm. What you have there is a syntax error. In fact, exactly the sort of syntax error you would get if you had a rogue space between the colon and the equals sign. You say that doesn't occur in your code? Very well. Either way we cannot help you diagnose your code if you don't post the actual code you're running (or at least an accurately redacted version of it).

Comment: If you wrote it as above, in one line `l_a := null and l_b := null;` then it will give this error. Write two lines: `l_a := null;` and second line `l_b := null;` in your exception.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo. It has to be `:=` instead of `: =`. Also you need to seperate the statements with a semicolon: `;`. Usually statements are in separate lines.

```
l_a := null;
l_b := null;
```

Besides that you do not need to assign null. Variables are assigned null initially and if no data is found they stay null.

Of course if the variable was assigned a value before the value stays. So you could also do this.

```
l_a := null;
l_b := null;
select column A, column B into l_a, l_b 
  from ......
-- do something with l_a and l_b here
exception 
  when no_data_found then 
    null; -- ignore and do nothing
```

But there is always many roads to Rome

Comment: I don't think that the first line of code you wrote compiles. This one: `l_a := null and l_b := null ;`

Comment: Yes, you did. Looks better now.